# Probability that random walk will reach state $k$ for the first time on step $n$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, random-walk

We have a random walk which starts in state $0$. At each step, a coin is tossed with probability of heads: $P(H)=p$. If we get a heads, we go to the next higher integer state and on tails, we go to the next lower integer state (so state $n$ would go to $n+1$ on heads and $n-1$ on tails).

Now, I want to know the probability that we will reach state $k$ for the first time after exactly $n$ tosses of the coin. Turning out to be surprisingly hard for me.

---

Here is my attempt:

I define $a_n^{k}$ as the probability described above and $c_n^k$ as the probability that the random walk will be in state $k$ at toss $n$ (regardless of if it was there in a previous toss).

It's clear that we need $\left(\frac{n-k}{2}\right)$ tails and $\left(\frac{n+k}{2}\right)$ heads. So if $n-k$ is not even, the sequences for those $n$'s become $0$.

To get $a_n^k$, we need to identify all sequences where the cumulative number of heads stays less than $k$ + the cumulative number of tails for all tosses leading upto $n$. This is not so easy to solve.

On the other hand, I got an expression for $c_n^k$ and hoped I could use it to get $a_n^k$. I reasoned that the probability the walk reaches $k$ for the first time on toss $n$ is the probability it is in state $k$ on toss $n$ subtracted by the probabilities that it was in state $k$ in any previous toss. So,

$$a_n^k = c_n^k - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i^k$$

But this can't be right since this expression will become negative for many values of $n$.

Comment: Still working on the solution to the question, but I do know why the reasoning at the end is wrong; the probabilities are not independent, so you can not simply subtract them from each other.

Comment: Appreciate it. Yeah, I suspected as much. That's almost always the reason when you add/subtract probabilities and get something not between 0 and 1. Thought I'd mention it anyway in case it inspired someone to formulate a correct approach based on the idea.

Comment: If you reverse time and flip the y axis, you are counting paths which reach k after n steps without ever returning to 0. This is Bertrand’s ballot problem.

Comment: Don't completely follow. If I reverse time, I start off at $k$, correct? So, doesn't it become paths that reach 0?

Comment: @RohitPandey Sorry, when I said "flip the y-axis,", I meant that you interchange $0$ with $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems to be the case that there are $$f(k,\ell)=\frac{k+1}{k+1+\ell}{k+2\ell\choose\ell}$$ paths to state $k\geq0$ in $k+2\ell$ steps that never pass the $k$'th state. This is equivalent to the amount of ways to move to state $k+1$ for the first time after $k+1+2\ell$ steps. By substitution and simple probability, we get a $$\frac{k}{k+\ell}{k-1+2\ell\choose\ell}p^{k+\ell}q^{\ell}$$ probability of reaching state $k$ for the first time after $k+2\ell$ steps.

We can prove our formula for $f$ by induction. For $\ell=0$ the answer is obviously $1$, which coincides with the given formula. For $k=-1$ the answer is obviously $0$, which also coincides with the given formula. For $\ell>0$ and $k\geq0$ we have two options for the first move: right or left. If we go left, there are $f(k+1,\ell-1)$ options, and if we go right there are $f(k-1,\ell)$ options. Hence, in total we have
\begin{align}
f(k+1,\ell-1)+f(k-1,\ell)
&=\frac{k+2}{k+2+\ell-1}{k+1+2(\ell-1)\choose\ell-1}+\frac{k}{k+\ell}{k-1+2\ell\choose\ell}
\\&=\frac{(k+2)(k+2\ell-1)!}{(k+\ell+1)(\ell-1)!(k+\ell)!}+\frac{k(k+2\ell-1)!}{(k+\ell)\ell!(k+\ell-1)!}
\\&=\frac{(k+2)(k+2\ell-1)!}{(\ell-1)!(k+\ell+1)!}+\frac{k(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell)!}
\\&=\frac{\ell(k+2)(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}+\frac{(k+\ell+1)k(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}
\\&=\frac{(\ell(k+2)+(k+\ell+1)k)(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}
\\&=\frac{(2\ell k+2\ell+k^2+k)(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}
\\&=\frac{(2\ell+k)(k+1)(k+2\ell-1)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}
\\&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2\ell)!}{\ell!(k+\ell+1)!}
\\&=f(k,\ell)
\end{align}
options. By principle of induction, this proves the correctness of the formula for $f$.

Now admittedly, even though this solves the problem, it is not a nice solution. I found the formula by simply experimenting for half an hour, and the proof is very algebraic and not very nice to look at. If someone comes up with a combinatorical proof, that would be much better! I am certainly going to think about it now.

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you briefly explain how you came up with this formula via experimentation? What was your approach to first discover it?

Comment: I took a fixed $\ell$ and I expected the formula would be a polynomial of degree $\ell-1$, so simply finding $\ell$ terms determines the polynomial. The first few polynomials were $1$; $k+1$; $(k+1)(k+4)/2$; $(k+1)(k+5)(k+6)/6$; $(k+1)(k+6)(k+7)(k+8)/24$. At this point I found the pattern and I got the formula.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing I haven't understood - why didn't you just call the probability $f(k,l) p^{k+l}q^l$? Instead, you wrote it as $f(k-1,l) p^{k+l} q^l$.

Comment: To go to state $k$ for the first time after $k+2\ell$ steps means to go to state $k-1$ after $k-1+2\ell$ steps without going past state $k-1$ and then going right.

Comment: Ahh, without going past being they key. Got it, thanks again! Impressive solution.

Comment: See below answer by me for a combinatorial explanation of @SmileyCraft's formula.

Answer (score 3):

**A Generating Function**

Let the number of ways for getting to position $s$ for the first time on step $n$ be $a_{s,n}$. The number of [unilateral walks of length $2k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124622) is $\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$, with generating function $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$. To first get to position $s$ on step $n$, we can count the number of ways to first get to position $s-1$ in $n-2k-1$ steps times the number of unilateral walks of length $2k$ and sum for all $k$. That is,
$$
a_{s,n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\,a_{s-1,n-2k-1}\tag1
$$
If we set the generating function
$$
f_s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{s,n}x^n\tag2
$$
then, using $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}x^{2k+1}$, the [Cauchy Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) and $(1)$ imply
$$
f_s(x)=f_{s-1}(x)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}\right)\tag3
$$
and since $f_0(x)=1$, induction yields
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f_s(x)=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{2x}\right)^{\large s}}\tag4
$$
Therefore, if the probability of a '$+1$' step is $p$ and of a '$-1$' step is $1-p$, then the probability of $\frac{n+s}2$ '$+1$' steps and $\frac{n-s}2$ '$-1$' steps is $a_{s,n}p^{\frac{n+s}2}(1-p)^{\frac{n-s}2}=\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{s/2}a_{s,n}(p(1-p))^{n/2}$. Summing over $n$ gives the probability of getting to position $s$ at all to be
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{s/2}f_s\!\left(\sqrt{p(1-p)}\right)
&=\left(\frac{1-|1-2p|}{2(1-p)}\right)^{\large s}\\[3pt]
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^s&\text{if }p\lt\frac12\\1&\text{if }p\ge\frac12\end{array}\right.\tag5
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Closed Form**

To derive a closed form for $a_{s,n}$, we first consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{s,n}x^n=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\right)^{\large s}\tag6
$$
where, comparing $(4)$ and $(6)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_{s,s+2n}&=b_{s,n}\\
a_{s,s+2n+1}&=0
\end{align}\tag7
$$
Using the fact that
$$
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\right)^2=\frac1x\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}-\frac1x\tag8
$$
we get the relation
$$
b_{s,n}=b_{s-1,n+1}-b_{s-2,n+1}\tag9
$$
We know that
$$
\begin{align}
b_{0,n}&=[n=0]\\[3pt]
b_{1,n}&=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n-1}
\end{align}\tag{10}
$$
which implies that
$$
\begin{align}
b_{2,n}&=\frac1{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n}-\binom{2n+1}{n-1}\tag{11}\\[6pt]
b_{3,n}&=\frac1{n+3}\binom{2n+4}{n+2}-\frac1{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}
=\binom{2n+2}{n}-\binom{2n+2}{n-1}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
A pattern is appearing; that is,
$$
\begin{align}
b_{s,n}
&=\binom{2n+s-1}{n}-\binom{2n+s-1}{n-1}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{s}{2n+s}\binom{2n+s}{n}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
which satisfies $(9)$ using [Pascal's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Formula). Therefore, applying $(7)$ yields
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a_{s,n}=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac sn\binom{n}{(n-s)/2}=\binom{n-1}{(n-s)/2}-\binom{n-1}{(n-s-2)/2}&\text{if }2\mid n-s\\
0&\text{if }2\nmid n-s
\end{array}\right.}\tag{14}
$$

Comment: In equation (2), should the index be on $n$ instead of $k$?

Comment: Very beautiful proof. To get an actual expression for $a_{s,n}$, we can use (5.70) here (in conjunction with equation (4)): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064256/proof-of-identity-about-generalized-binomial-sequences. 

This identity isn't super easy to prove, but it gets one there.

Comment: @RohitPandey: Indeed. I am working on more for the answer. As soon as I post that, the correction will be there.

Comment: @RohitPandey: I have added a derivation of the closed form as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, reading through. In the meantime, I'm writing a paper on how races of wealthy gamblers can be used to estimate $\pi$. I think this provides a method that converges to $\pi$ reasonably fast and has a nice interpretation as well. I'll be done with the first draft very soon. Would love to have you as a co-author since your answers have helped a lot with the effort. Let me know if you're fine with it. If not, is it OK to cite your answers in it?

Comment: I have no problem citing my answer.  I'd rather not be a coauthor of a paper I've not even seen yet :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88593/discussion-between-rohit-pandey-and-robjohn).

Comment: @RohitPandey: I think what you added in your edit is the same as the justification preceding $(1)$.

Comment: Fair enough, removed the edit. Can I add some description for "unilateral paths" and also flesh out the steps that lead to equation (3)? These two are not obvious and make reading the answer a little but harder (and I re-read it often).

Comment: I will look at it. It would be better to mention what is not clear in a comment and then I can edit the answer. These are more substantive changes that the author should make.

Comment: @RohitPandey: I have added a bit of explanation for $(3)$. If you feel that something else needs added explanation, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is good.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an extension to the one by @SmileyCraft. As he says in his answer, it would be nice to have a combinatorial proof. I might have found one. The problem seems similar in spirit to the one where you have a square grid, start at the bottom left corner and need to get to the top-right corner and find the number of paths where you don't *cross* the main diagonal of the grid (ok to touch it). In that instance, the number of such paths is the catalan numbers.

$$C_n = \frac{2n \choose n}{n+1} =  {2n \choose n} - {2n \choose n-1}$$

Now, taking a cue from this, the formula @SmileyCraft has above can also be written as:

$$f(k,l) = \frac{k+1}{k+1+l} {k+2l \choose l} = {k+2l \choose l} - {k+2l \choose l-1} \tag{1}$$

Now, the problem here for the random walk not crossing $k$ can be converted to a grid problem. We basically have (per @SmileyCraft's convention) $l$ tails and $l+k$ heads and need to arrange them in such a way as to never cross the $k$. This is completely equivalent to saying we'll go right if we get a tails and up if we get a heads on a grid which has $l+k$ rows and $l$ columns.

Another way to see this is to plot on the x-axis the toss number and on the y-axis the score of the random walk. Now, imagine any path going from $(0,0)$ to $(k+2l,k)$. Now, simply rotate the whole picture by 45 degrees and you'll get the grid.

So the formula for $f(k,l)$ above is simply the number of ways to go from the bottom left to top right of a grid with $l$ rows and $l+k$ columns in such a way that the path never crosses the line $y=x+k$.

But how do we show that is equivalent to equation (1) above? I cheated and used the same reasoning as the answer by @Marcus M [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510816/number-of-pathsin-a-grid-with-restrictions). It goes like this:

We know the total paths in our grid are $k+2l \choose l$.
The good paths are ones that never cross the line $y=x+k$. Then,

# good paths = # paths - # bad paths

Now, any bad path does cross the line $y=x+k$. So, it must touch the line $y=x+k+1$ (the diagonal just above it).

Divide any such path into two portions. The portion from the origin to when it touches the $y=x+k+1$ line and the portion after that. The first portion can be reflected about the $y=x+k+1$. And this leads to a bijection to a path from $(-(k+1),(k+1))$ to $(l,k+l)$. So, the bad paths can be mapped to paths from the bottom left to top-right of another grid whose height is $(k+l)-(k+1)=l-1$. But we didn't change the total path length, so the total length of the bad paths is still $k+2l$. Hence, the number of bad paths is $k+2l \choose l-1$.

Putting all of this together, we get equation (1) above. The picture below shows this for $k=3$ and $t=2$.

[image]

Comment: I believe you are confusing your lefts and rights somewhere, but I get the proof and it is very satisfying :)

Comment: Yes, I did have left and right mixed up in one place. Fixed that - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can solve this problem in a less combinatorial way.

For easier understanding, I will just give a sketch of the proof.

> Some abbreviations:
>
> - SRW = Simple Random Walk
> - [L/R]HS = [left/right] hand side
> - i.i.d. = independent and identically distributed
> - # = number

---

First I need to introduce **Reflection Principle for SRW**.

Consider SRW: $S_n=X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ and $S_0=0$. $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ are i.i.d. random variables.

Denote $M_n$ is the farthest position we can reach in $n$ steps (more formally, $M_n=\max_{i\in[0,n]} S_i$). Then

$$
\#(M_n\geqslant x, S_n=y) = \#(S_n=2x-y), \quad \text{if}~~x\geqslant y
\tag{Reflection Principle}
$$

This is intuitive:

1. $x$ is visited before or at $n$ (exists $t\leqslant n$, such that $S_t=x$);
2. For each path in LHS, you can "reflect" or "flip" all the behaviors after $t$ to get a path in RHS, and vice versa.

---

Then we can easily solve this problem.

Since it is possible only when $n$ and $k$ have the same oddity, and $n\geqslant k$, we can denote $n=k+2l$.

$$
\begin{split}
 & \#(\text{first visit $k$ at $n$th step}) \\
=& \#(M_{n-1}\leqslant k-1, S_{n-1}=k-1) \\
=& \#(S_{n-1}=k-1) - \#(M_{n-1}\geqslant k, S_{n-1}=k-1) \\
=& \#(S_{n-1}=k-1) - \#(S_{n-1}=k+1) \\
=& \binom{n-1}{k+l-1} - \binom{n-1}{k+l} \\
\end{split}
$$

---

We can use 2 simple cases to test this result:

1. $\#=1$ when $n=k$ or $l=0$:
   $$\binom{k-1}{k-1} - \binom{k-1}{k} = 1 - 0 = 1$$
2. $\#=k$ when $n=k+2$ or $l=1$:
   $$\binom{k+1}{k} - \binom{k+1}{k+1} = (k+1) - 1 = k$$