$f(x) = \sum_{n}\binom{2n+k}{n}x^n$

Proof of the following identity
$$\tag{1}\sum_{n}\binom{2n+k}{n}x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\bigg)^{k}$$
for $k \in \Bbb N$

This question sprout directly from answering this one, where this identity is the correct solution for the problem. How can we prove this? The first time I see this kind of question was linked to snake oil method, and linked document is where I find $(1)$ . So I think one can try with this method. Wikipedia generating function page's suggest to try with
$$\sum_{n}\binom{2n}{n}z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = f(z)$$
and use Cauchy integral formula or contour integration and only after generalize the formula for our question. So I think to use Laurent series expansion and
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}}d\zeta $$
After this little research I still don't know how to tackle down this problem. Any help appreciated!

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4025969/42969 – found with Approach0

You could use $\binom{a}{b}=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+z)^a\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi iz^{b+1}}$ followed by the residue theorem.

@J.G. would you be so kind to elaborate a little bit further since is the first time I'm seeing the identity you're presenting to me.

You can prove it with the binomial theorem plus $\oint\frac{z^{k-1}\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}=\delta_{k0}$. Your series is$$\oint\sum_n\frac{(1+z)^{2n+k}x^n}{2\pi iz^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z.$$The integrand is a geometric series.

After some practicing and research on MathSE a way to prove the identity is Cauchy Integral Formula and some power series identity. What I want to show is that
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\bigg)^k$$
has as $n-$th coefficient in its power series expansion around the origin
$$a_n = \binom{2n+k}{n}$$
for the unicity of this expansion we prove our identity. We know that for CIF, that holds in a suitable neighborhood of the origin where the function is holomorphic, this coefficient is
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{|z|=\delta} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta ^{n+1}}d\zeta = \frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{|z|=\delta}\frac{1}{\zeta^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4\zeta}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\zeta}}{2\zeta}\bigg)^kd\zeta$$
the form of the integral suggest $\xi = \sqrt{1-4\zeta}$ as a change of variables. Here we have to notice near the origin $\xi = 1- 2z + \dots$ and the new contour could be deformed to $\gamma := \{|\xi-1|= 2\delta\}$
$$\begin{align*}a_n &= -\frac{1}{2\cdot 2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-\xi^2)^{n+1}}(1-\xi)^k \frac{2^k}{(1-\xi^2)^k}d\xi\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\cdot2^{k+2n+1}}{2\pi i }\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(\xi-1)^{n+1}}\frac{1}{(\xi +1)^{k+n+1}}d\xi\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\cdot2^{n}}{2\pi i }\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(\xi-1)^{n+1}}\frac{1}{\bigg(1 +\frac{(\xi -1)}{2}\bigg)^{k+n+1}}d\xi
\end{align*}$$
here I want to expand in power series expansion and
$$\bigg(1 +\frac{(\xi -1)}{2}\bigg)^{-(k+n+1)} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\binom{n+k+j}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^j}(\xi-1)^j $$
and in order to obtain the residue $j = n$, in conclusion
$$\boxed{a_n =\frac{(-1)^n\cdot2^{n}}{2\pi i } \cdot 2\pi i \ \text{Res}(1)  = \binom{2n + k}{n}}$$

I think a similar approach could be used to prove
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} = \sum_n \binom{2n}{n}x^n$$

You need to specify your contours. The change of variable produces a different contour centered at one as opposed to at zero.

@MarkoRiedel Since this answer is highly inspired by yours, I'm using mine as a personal trace on this problem. That part I wasn't very sure about since I don't fully understand how the transformation $w = w(z)$ work. If you would mine to fill the gaps I leave in my answer I would be super happy. Thank you very much inn any case!

If you do not specify the contour the second pole at $\xi=-1$ could end up inside the image contour, invalidating the result. Also, you lost a differential. Furthermore your Laurent series should start at $j=0$ or it gives a value of zero rather than one. The lower index of that series is not related to the center of the second contour.

When you choose your original contour the important observation is that it must not intersect the branch cut, in particular the pole at $\zeta=1/4.$ The square root is defined in terms of the prinicipal branch of the logarithm with cut on the negative real axis. So, the square root ends up with the cut on $[1/4,\infty).$
